# Making Scala version of this Java method functional

Tags: scala

Trying to port following Java method to Scala. Ending up with a lot of nested Map and ugly return statement from "foreach". converted method looks ugly just like its OO counterpart in Java.

Comment: I would start by breaking this big, complex function into a bunch of small single-operation functions.  That should help you get a better idea of how to do the translation.

Comment: Easier if you post your ugly Scala.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of looping through lanes to locate a value, you want to `lanes find (_.number == 42)`.

Express the guards as filters and default values as `getOrElse`.

Sample:

```
scala> case class Lane(number: Int)
defined class Lane

scala> val lanes: Seq[Lane] = Nil
lanes: Seq[Lane] = List()

scala> Option(lanes) filter (_.nonEmpty) flatMap (_.find(_.number == 42))
res0: Option[Lane] = None

scala> Option(lanes) filter (_.nonEmpty) flatMap (_.find(_.number == 42)) map (_.number) getOrElse -1
res1: Int = -1
```

or

```
scala> for (x <- Option(lanes); y <- x.find(_.number == 42)) yield y.number
res3: Option[Int] = None
```

Then refactor predicates out to little functions to get `x find goodNumber` and so on.

More feedback:

Folding is laudable, but usually you want to use `max` or `maxBy` if that's what you're doing.

```
spots maxBy (_.name.toInt)
```

You could express your missing condition as part of a fold, but it's easier just to scan the list again:

```
if (spots exists (!_.model.equalsIgnoreCase(vehicle.model))) fail
```

You can optimize later if necessary.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated question with what my revised Scala solution looks like along with open questions.

Comment: `for (x <- Option(lanes); y <- x.find(_.number == 42)) yield y.number` could be simplified to `for (x <- lanes if x.number == 42) yield x`, unless you need the Option wrapper for non-matching values.