# Return second string if first is empty?

Tags: scala

Here is an idiom I find myself writing.

```
def chooseName(nameFinder: NameFinder) = {
  if(nameFinder.getReliableName.isEmpty) nameFinder.getReliableName
  else nameFinder.secondBestChoice
}
```

In order to avoid calling `getReliableName()` twice on `nameFinder`, I add code that makes my method look less elegant.

```
def chooseName(nameFinder: NameFinder) = {
  val reliableName = nameFinder.getReliableName()
  val secondBestChoice = nameFinder.getSecondBestChoice()
  if(reliableName.isEmpty) reliableName
  else secondBestChoice
}
```

This feels dirty because I am creating an unnecessary amount of state using the `vals` for no reason other than to prevent a duplicate method call. Scala has taught me that whenever I feel dirty there is almost always a better way.

Is there a more elegant way to write this?

```
Here's two Strings, return whichever isn't empty while favoring the first
```

Comment: I know you've probably heard this before, but optimising on a method call is pretty extreme.

Comment: Might be a DB call or something though.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to always call `getSecondBestChoice`, of course. Personally, I find nothing inelegant about the code after changing that  - it's clear what it does, has no mutable state. The other answers just seem overcomplicated just to avoid using a `val`

```
def chooseName(nameFinder: NameFinder) = {
  val reliableName = nameFinder.getReliableName()

  if(reliableName.isEmpty) reliableName
  else nameFinder.getSecondBestChoice()
}
```

If you really want to avoid the val, here's another variant (generalises well if there are more than two alternatives)

```
List(nameFinder.getReliableName(), nameFinder.getSecondBestChoice()).find(_.nonEmpty).get
```

(or `getOrElse(lastResort)` if everything in the list may be empty too)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way using `Option`. It's not that much prettier, but everything is called only once. This assumes you want a `String` as a result, and don't care if the second string is empty.

```
Some(nameFinder.getReliableName)
    .filter(_.nonEmpty)
    .getOrElse(nameFinder.secondBestChoice)
```

Comment: I would prefer `Option(nameFinder.getReliableName)`, which would handler `null` as `None`, if wrapping Java type.

Comment: But you're calling Some.apply, Some.filter, Some.getOrElse. If his aim is to avoid as many method calls as possible, this is even worse.

Comment: @monkjack I believe the point was to avoid calling `nameFinder.getReliableName` multiple times to remove the redundancy.

Comment: If `getReliableName` is a pretty complex method, then this code will be better. Without any `val` and without more method calls, I think the question is well... Can we do that without them?

Answer (score 2):

```
Option(namefinder.getReliableName) // transforms a potential null into None
.filter(_.trim.nonEmpty) // "" is None, but also "   "
.getOrElse(nameFinder.secondBestChoice)
```

Or better, if you can modify `getReliableName` to return an `Option[String]`:

```
def chooseName(nameFinder: NameFinder): String =
  namefinder.getReliableName getOrElse nameFinder.secondBestChoice
```

Finally, if `secondBestChoice` can fail as well (assuming it returns an `Option[String]`):

```
def chooseName(nameFinder: NameFinder): Option[String] =
  namefinder.getReliableName orElse nameFinder.secondBestChoice
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need it more than once:

```
scala> implicit class `nonempty or else`(val s: String) extends AnyVal {
     | def nonEmptyOrElse(other: => String) = if (s.isEmpty) other else s }
defined class nonempty

scala> "abc" nonEmptyOrElse "def"
res2: String = abc

scala> "" nonEmptyOrElse "def"
res3: String = def
```

Comment: just pay attention to the `null` case. If `getReliableName` can return a `null` (perhaps it's java code), doing `getReliableName.nonEmptyOrElse` can be dangerous.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella True, but that's not the use case; and it's easy to add, so, kind of beside the point. But I'm not averse to Option by any means: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23126703/1296806

Answer (score 0):

Using the following pattern matching may deliver a neater scalish code,

```
def chooseName(nameFinder: NameFinder) = {
  nameFinder.getReliableName match {
    case r if r.isEmpty => r
    case _              => nameFinder.secondBestChoice
  }
}
```